# WPF Group Style is disturbing wrap panel wrapping

Tags: wpf, xaml, grouping, styling

I am using WrapPanel (with vertical orientation) as items panel for ItemsControl. Items are properly warpping without adding a group style. When i add a group style for items control then wrappanel is not wrapping items, all items are getting displayed vertically in a single column instead of spanning in to multiple columns. I am not using any complex layout for both group header or for ItemTemplate.

Here is the XAML source..

```
     <Grid>
            <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                        MaxHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Grid}},Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figure out the problem.

When using GroupStyle we need to mention GroupStyle.Panel otherwise default panel will be used 
which is a stackpanel.

The ItemsPanel which have declared as Wrappanel will not be used as main panel for group items layout.

```
                   <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"></WrapPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
```

Comment: I am using wrappanel for wrapping items in items control (see ItemsControl.ItemsPanel section in my question.). when we use group style wpf will ignore items control panel and will use group panel, because it needs to implement group style. so in my case it is ignoring my wrappanle and using default panle in group style which is stackpanel

Answer (score 0):

When you setup the `GroupDescription` as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), your items will be grouped into `GroupItem` collection and each group will be added as child to a Vertical `StackPanel`. The items inside a `GroupItem` will still use the `WrapPanel` you have defined as ItemsPanel, but since your `WrapPanel`'s `Orientation` is set to `Vertical` and you are a descendant of a `Vertical` `StackPanel` (which gives Infinite vertical available space) the layout system does not wrap the items since it has all the space it needs to display the Items in a vertical manner.

Hope it made it clearer now and you can adapt your solution, maybe change the `WrapPanel`'s `Orientation` to `Horizontal`.

Answer (score 0):

below code (xaml) works in my case:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```